# ng-show/ng-hide based on function call

Tags: ng-show, date-comparison, ng-hide

I'm trying to compare two dates in a controller function and returning true/false to ng-show and ng-hide based on the logic in the controller, but it is not working as expected, below is the plnkr for the same. Can someone please help me figure out what is the issue.

http://plnkr.co/edit/CWvb1uy0PeYFb0Tf34rY?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.SetDate=function(dt)
  {
    $scope.NewDt=$filter('date')(dt, 'shortDate');
     $scope.currentDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'shortDate');   
     $scope.parsedCurr=Date.parse($scope.currentDate);
     $scope.parsedFuture= Date.parse($scope.NewDt);

        if ( $scope.parsedCurr <$scope.parsedFuture) {
            return true;
        }  
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are denying twice, you have:

```
<span ng-hide="!SetDate('2015-12-31T00:00:00')">
```

and you need

```
<span ng-hide="SetDate('2015-12-31T00:00:00')">
```

Comment: thanks marjes, I did notice that and corrected it. i'm actually using this in ng-repeat for a list, unfortunately it is getting applied properly for some li's and not for some...any idea what could be the reason

Comment: maybe you can put the code in plnkr or take a picture, for now i think if it work for part, is becouse in some "li" you send a incorrect var, maybe you date array have some rows with bad data

Comment: Ajay Srikanth, Do not forget, choose the answer that helped you

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to check are the two parsed dates I would do the check in the ng-show to simplify the code.

```
<span ng-show="parsedCurr < parsedFuture">
      You can see me!
</span>
<span ng-hide="parsedCurr < parsedFuture">
      You can't see me :(
</span>
```

Or if you wan't to use the funtion just change the logic slightly and use either ng-show or ng-hide.  Like this:

```
$scope.SetDate=function(dt)
  {
    $scope.NewDt=$filter('date')(dt, 'shortDate');
     $scope.currentDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'shortDate');   
     $scope.parsedCurr=Date.parse($scope.currentDate);
     $scope.parsedFuture= Date.parse($scope.NewDt);

        if ( $scope.parsedCurr < $scope.parsedFuture) {
            return true;
        }  
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
  }
```

And your markup like this:

```
<span ng-show="SetDate('2015-12-31T00:00:00')">
          SHOW ME
</span>
<br>
<span ng-hide="SetDate('2015-12-31T00:00:00')">
          HIDE ME
</span>
```